# Split Delimited String into Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I want to split a string into columns. After using attached code I am getting `NULL` data. Could someone help on this issue please?

```
CREATE TABLE #custAddress13(
   rowdata VARCHAR(max)
);

INSERT INTO #custAddress13(rowdata)
VALUES('13946005|13946005|10266|10266|CENTRAL FURNITURE & APPLIANCES, INC.|273|DAVID LUCE|01|000||||26 RIVER ST||SANFORD|ME|04073-9999|United States|2073245474|2074905182|')


SELECT 
  REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 1)) AS [L1]
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 2)) AS [L2]
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 3)) AS L3
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 4)) AS L4
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 5)) AS L5
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 6)) AS L6
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 7)) AS L7
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 8)) AS L8
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 9)) AS L9
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 10)) AS L10
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 11)) AS L11
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 12)) AS L12
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 13)) AS L13
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 14)) AS L14
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 15)) AS L15
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 16)) AS L16
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 17)) AS L17
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 18)) AS L18
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 19)) AS L19
    , REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(RowDATA), '|', '.'), 20)) AS L20
FROM #custAddress13;
GO
```

Comment: `PARSENAME` only goes up to `4` for the 2nd parameter, not `20`. It's designed to split object names into parts.

Comment: Ideally I would fix what ever process is passing the data and have it properly put them into columns to start with.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: If you're thinking `STRING_SPLIT`, @squillman , I'd be careful; it makes no promises it'll retain the ordinal positions of the values.

Comment: A few years ago i had a similar problem, i used CLR user defined functions to implement a solution. I dont have access to the code anymore, but it was not complicated to write.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU22-GDR) (KB4583457) - 14.0.3370.1 (X64) Sql version

Comment: It looks to me like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15108499/1115360) in [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns) would be a suitable solution.

Comment: The PARSENAME function works because the function has the ability to return a value from a specified position in a "Dot" delimited string. It does have a limitation that it will not work with more than four (4) delimited values within a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a bit a JSON

**Example**

```
Select L1  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[0]')
      ,L2  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[1]')
      ,L3  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[2]')
      ,L4  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[3]')
      ,L5  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[4]')
      ,L6  = JSON_VALUE(S,'$[5]')  --<< Expand to L20 / $[19]
From #custAddress13 A
Cross Apply ( values ( '["'+replace(replace(A.rowdata,'"','\"'),'|','","')+'"]' ) ) B(S)
```

**[or dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=092f3f26737462030c6ea895f74741ca)**

Comment: It looks like there is a canonical question at [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns), but it lacks the via-JSON method you've shown here.